# scipy cumtrapz() division by zero or modulo

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, scipy

I have pulled data from a .csv with `pandas` to plot with `matplotlib.pyplot`. My data date/time format is for every 5 minutes, but I need to integrate over 1 days time in order to make one data point for each day.

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "integrating.py", line 25, in <module>
    plt.plot(times, integ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3317, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1406, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 407, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 395, in _plot_args
    seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I suspect a formatting issue, because when I use the arrays below then it works. I've tried turning the `datas` into an array, but i'm not sure if it's worth pursuing further. I also know that this section of the data does not contain any zeros, so I don't know exactly why it's telling me this.

Any help is much appreciated. I really just want to get it working even if I need to take another direction. Thanks!

The format of my data after pulled from the csv is:

```
     Data
367                   3
368                   4
369                   5
370                   5
371                   6
372                   7
373                   8
374                   8
375                   9
376                  10
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import integrate

file = pd.read_csv("Compiled.csv",parse_dates=['Date/Time'])
times = file.loc[367:432, ['Date/Time']]
datas = file.loc[367:432, ['Data']]

#times = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
#datas = [1,2,3,4,5,0,3,2,1]

plt.plot(times, scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(datas, x=None))
plt.show()
```

Solution:

```
times = datas['Date/Time'].loc[367:532]
integ = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(datas['Data'].loc[366:532].values, x=None)
plt.plot(times, integ)
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, including stack trace.

Comment: what an unfortunate name for a function

Comment: In general, SciPy functions are not designed to handle Pandas DataFrames, so their behavior with one is unpredictable.  Convert your data to a numpy array before passing it to `cumtrapz`.  And check the shape of the array; `cumtrapz` accepts multidimensional arrays and chooses which axis to integrate using the `axis` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should work is to supply the values as an array to the `cumtrapz` function,

```
integ = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(datas['Data'].values, x=None)
```

Since `integ` then has one value less than `datas`, your plotting needs to account for that

```
plt.plot(times.loc[1:], scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(datas, x=None))
```

Also this will only work it `times` contains numerical data or `datetime` objects.

Comment: Yes! This works. Thank you! I tried a few different variations of using `.value` but something about how it is structured here made it work.